# Does apache spark auto add filter to decrease shuffle size prior to join?

Tags: apache-spark

Say that I am joining 2 dataframes and joining on column1

```
DF1
    column1: range[1 : 2billion]
DF2 
    column1: range[500million : 1billion]
```

if I have `df1.join(df2)`

Is spark smart enough to know that we can first

1. find the max of column1 for both df1 and df2 , find the min of the two max = lower_max
2. find the min of column1 for both df1 and df2, find the max of two min = upper_min
3. prior to join, filter df1 such that only take data within [upper_min, lower_max] during map phase
4. prior to join filter df2 such that only take data within [upper_min, lower_max] during map_phase
5. perform join

This should automatically decrease the shuffling cost dramatically

Or do I have to manually broadcast the variables

```
val min1 = df1.agg(min("column1")).head().get(0)
val min2 = df2.agg(min("column1")).head().get(0)
val upper_min = max(min1, min2)
val upper_min_broadcast = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(upper_min)


val df1_bound = df1
  .filter(col("column1") >= upper_min_broadcast.value)

val df2_bound = df2
  .filter(col("column1") >= upper_min_broadcast.value)


val join_result = df1.join(df2)
```